# How to get oneDrive file "Shard By" information

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I know I can use Microsoft graph api to get a list of users with which a oneDrive file is shared, using the `grantedTo` field returned by the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.
I wanted to know id there is a way to get the user who shared the oneDrive's file with those `grantedTo` users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `shareId` returned by the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#:%7E:text=Sharing%20permission%20properties) endpoint, you can get an insight representing shared file

```
GET /v1.0/users/{user_id}/insights/shared/{id}
```

Where `user_id` is the `id` of the user with whom the file is shared.

The returned object has the [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/insights-shared?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) `lastShared` with the info about the user [who shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/insights-sharingdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties:%7E:text=Description-,sharedBy,-insightIdentity) the document

If you don't know the `shareId` then you need to list all insights and filter them

```
GET /v1.0/users/{user_id}/insights/shared
GET /v1.0/me/insights/shared?$filter=resourceReference/type eq 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'
```

and if you know `driveId` and `driveItemId`, filter items on the client side by `resourceReference/id`

Server side filtering by `resourceReference/id` seems to be not working/supported

```
GET /v1.0/me/insights/shared?$filter=resourceReference/id eq 'drives/{driveId}/items/{driveItemId}'
```

Comment: but insights only returns items shares with the signed-in user and I want to get a way to retrieve this info for any user @user2250152

Comment: @eladm26 Have you tried /users/{user_id}/insights/shared instead of /me/insights/shared ?

Comment: yeah @user2250152, returns an error

Comment: nvm, my bad, I just needed to add my app application permissions and not delegated